# How to inform a Java Program that the data of a DB have changed

Tags: java, mysql

I created a Java program that every 30 Minutes, reads information from a database, keeping them in a structure [`Vector<Vector<Object>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).
To do this use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

I created a second Java program that allows you to Add/Modify/Delete items from the database. How do I inform the first program that some changes took place in the database and then re-read the new information without waiting the 30 minutes?

The first program is always active, while the second is executed only in the case where it is necessary to make a change.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add/modify/delete items only from the second java program you can call a method of the first program.

The easiest way to do that is to expose a web service from the first program that can be called from the second every time the database has been modified.

But if you can modify the database items also directly on the database you need to create a trigger on the database and invoke the web service directly from the database. Note that this second approach (calling a ws directly on trigger events) is a bad practice. In this case you can combine both procedures: call directly a ws if a modifications happens from the second java program and leave the polling active for modifications done directly on the database.

Comment: You mean activate a socket service on the first program to allow communication between them?

Comment: Yes activate a socket if the second program is not a web application, otherwise directly expose a web service if the other program is a web application.

Comment: @JoeJoe, you should "activate" any means to allow program2 to communicate with program1. It could be sockets (if network access among them is OK), writing to a mutually accessible file, pinging... it depends on your deploying scenario.

Comment: @bruno, i've think to use a shared file, but I should create another thread to constantly monitoring the shared file every N seconds. Think is best to use the way of the File or one of Socket? 
In my case, both scenarios are applicable

Comment: I finally decided to use the Socket, so that my independent program from the platform where the program is first run.

Comment: Yes, @JoeJoe. Using a socket, it's up to the OS to "pool" the stream for changes.